# How to get place type with latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I can use place api to know what type place near.
Just like the following video teach：https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Oljjn1fIAc&t=304s.
My question is when I input latitude and longitude , How to do that I can know what kind of place type with latitude and longitude in android studio.
Sorry , English is so bad...

Comment: What do you mean by "what kind of place"? Please clarify your question...

Comment: Just like I have a latitude and longitude(99999,99999) and there is a Starbucks so when I input the (99999,99999) ,  the app will reply me coffee

Comment: I want take FB check-in data that have very kinds of place ,like restaurant , coffee or bank ,so I want know how many places that  place has type [restaurant]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types    I want to know what type is the input Latitude and longitude

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "Of what type are Lat and Lon?"

Lat and Lon are both doubles.

Comment: Thank you  but I what to know the place type just like I input a Lat and Lon that is Starbucks there  and app will reply me a cafe